# How to change startup application in Windows CE?

Tags: windows-ce, startup

I have a Vipa 62g-fee0-cb touch panel which has as operating system Windows CE. Whe I open the touch panel it opens with windows. What I want, is to open an application I made (in Movicon) when the panel opens. I found a [PDF](https://vipausa.com/content/manuals/hmi/HB160E_TP_62G-FEE0_15-23_01.pdf) where explains how to set an application as startup, I followed the steps (page 29 from the pdf), but doesn't work at all. Is there something else I should do to achieve what I want? Many thanks in advance!